Error al enviar email con javamail: app.js:249 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
Tengo este controller:
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmailController {

    @Autowired
    private IEmailService emailService;

    @PostMapping(value= "/send-email", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(@RequestBody EmailDto email) throws MessagingException {
        emailService.sendMail(email);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("{\"message\":\"Correo enviado exitosamente\"}", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

La configuración de email está ok, pero el problema es que cuando hago la solicitud con postman me redirige a la pagina de index de mi app, devuelve el html del index, ni siquiera entra en el controlador

¿Cómo es la url que usas para hacer la petición? ¿Cómo está declarado el Controller? Sólo vemos el método, pero las anotaciones de la clase son también importantes

Estpas enviando un email, pero con el doctype arriba ?

La url es: http://localhost:8080/api/send-email

El error Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON, es porque interpreta un html que debería ser en json, ese es el problema, la url de la petición no le hace caso, como que redirige directamente al index de la aplicación y toma ese html. Tengo configurado springSecurity ok, para que permita explicitamente esta peticion:   .antMatchers("/api/send-email").permitAll() // Permitir acceso sin autenticación
